# Hive - Complex regexp_replace

Tags: csv, hadoop, hive

I'm not a specialist with regular expression and I'm facing issues using regexp_replace in Hive.

I would like to load a CSV file into Hive, which contains rows like that:

```
AAA,1234,BBB,,,"""CC,CCC""","""DDD""","""EE"EEE""",,
"""AAA""",1234,BBB,,,CCCC,"""DD,DD""",,"""FFFF""",
```

As you can see, the format isn't perfect

- There are non-escaped commas into string fields
- Some string fields are enclosed by """ (3 double-quotes)
- There are non-escaped double-quotes into string fields
- There are empty fields

When I try to import it into a Hive table, the columns are not well parsed because of the non-escaped commas.

So I imported the raw data as rows into a Hive table like this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE MyRawTable
(
    RAW_DATA STRING
)
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/path/to/hdfs/file'
```

And i'm trying to use the regexp_replace function to transform the rows:

- Escape the commas, the double and simple quotes in the string fields
- Not enclose string fields by double quotes

So data will look like that:

```
AAA,1234,BBB,,,CC\,CCC,DDD,EE\"EEE,,
AAA,1234,BBB,,,CCCC,DD\,DD,,FFFF,
```

I don't find the solution for this regex, any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about the regexp, you don't need it. The commas aren't escaped, but they are surrounded by double-quotes. You can simply use the [OpenCSVSerde](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/CSV+Serde) :

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE yourtable(foo int, bar string) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
   "separatorChar" = ",",
   "quoteChar"     = "\"",
   "escapeChar"    = "\""
)  
LOCATION '/your/folder/containing/csv/files/';
```